# Greek Alphabet support in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Is there a way of creating a `fabric.Text` object that is a greek letter (Γ, Δ, Ε for example)? When I put their code in the text field it just returns the actual code itself in the stage (codes like & #915;).

Comment: Fabric should have no problem displaying non-english characters, as long as font supports them. We simply delegate to canvas native fillText/strokeText and canvas should take care of those.

Comment: Use UTF-8 encoding, or die.